# VB Linq Double Grouping Error

Tags: .net, vb.net, linq

I have a Datatable in my VB code that I want to group in two levels (In other words group within another group) and I'm having a problem doing it.

For illustration's sake, suppose my datatable, `MyTable`, had columns as follows:

```
Name1     Name2    Start_Date    End_Date   Var1    Var2
```

So, supposing I wanted to just group it by, say, `Name1`, I could do it as follows:

```
Dim Query1 = From dr as DataRow in MyTable
             Group dr by Name1 = dr.Item("Name1") into Group
```

And then I could loop through all the records in that group doing something along the lines of:

```
For Each Grp in Query1
   For Each dr as DataRow in Grp.Rows
      ... do whatever ...
   Next
Next
```

Now, I would like to create a double group - For Example, suppose I wanted to create an in-memory query that first groups by `Start_Date` and `End_Date` and then, WITHIN THAT GROUP, a second grouping by `Name1` so I could write a loop along the lines of:

```
For Each MainGrp in BiggerQuery
   For Each SubGrp in MainGrp
        For Each dr as DataRow in SubGrp .Rows
            ... do whatever ...
        Next
   Next
Next
```

How would that double-grouped Linq query look in VB? - My first issue is that it seems that VB requires you to name your group `Group`, which doesn't allow for double-grouping and secondly, I can't seem to figure out the query as a whole.

Thanks!!!

Comment: You can always use the method syntax with `GroupBy`, even in the loop: `For Each group in Grp.Rows.GroupBy(Function(r)r.Field(Of String)("Name"))`.

Comment: @Tim, that is a pretty cool soution and I'm going to try it now... But the first thought that comes to my mind is how would I loop through those (sub)groups??

Comment: The same way you loop through the main-group - with `For Each` - for example. Note that you lso could mix method- and query-syntax or build all groups in one query. But in VB.NET i prefer to split those queries in multiples for for reasons of readability.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Dim query = From dr1 As DataRow In MyTable
            Group dr1 By New With { .StartDate = dr1.StartDate, .EndDate = dr1.EndDate } Into g1 = Group
            Select newGroup = (From dr2 As DataRow In g1
                    Group dr2 By dr2.Name1 Into g2 = Group
                    Select g2)
```

I think it should work, but cannot test it right now.

**EDIT**

There is a nice example of nested grouping on MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/bb737908#grpbynest

**EDIT2**

```
From dr1 As DataRow In myTable
Group dr1 By gi1 = New With {.StartDate = dr1.Item("StartDate"), .EndDate = dr1.Item("EndDate")} Into g1 = Group
Select newGroup = (From dr2 As DataRow In g1
                   Group dr2 By gi2 = dr2.Item("Name1") Into g2 = Group
                   Select g2)
```

Comment: I'm trying that now, but automatically +1 for the `Into g1 = Group` syntax!!! - That already solves one problem right off the bat!! THANK YOU!!!

Comment: ... I'm thinking that because it's a datatable, I'm getting an error - This line: `Group dr By New With {.var1 = dr.Item("Start Date"), .var2 = dr.Item("End Date")} Into Grp = Group` is bring up the error **"Range variable name can be inferred only from a simple or qualified name with no arguments."** - Any thoughts??

Comment: I've edited the query. According to that info: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb763056.aspx the problem is connected with a subquery.

Comment: ... I'm still getting the error on the `Group dr By New With {.StartDate = dr.Item("Start Date")} Into Grp = Group` line - Even when I simplified it as shown... Sorry about this and thanks for helping, by the way!!!

Comment: OK, I've checked it and prepared another version. Could you test it on your environment?

Comment: HOLY COW!!! - That is ugly as can be and I would **NEVER** have manage to have figured it out by myself, but it worked like a charm! @MarcinJuraszek, **THANK YOU SO MUCH!!!!!**